# Valores asignados en variables se limpian

Tags: android-studio, clase

Buenos días, necesito de su apoyo.
Lo que sucede es que tengo una aplicación que usa conexiones a web service. Todo funciona muy bien, pero cada cierto tiempo indeterminado me sucede algo extraño: las valores que he asignado a variables principales en una clase (clase que uso constantemente) se limpian. toman un valor vacío. la memoria tiene espacio libre, no hay más aplicaciones abiertas, ni procesos en segundo plano. Opté por usar el final, pero sucede lo mismo.

Algo que puedo estar obviando?
Pongo la clase donde he declarado las variables.

```
public class Usuario {

//Campos
public static String imei;
public static String companiaSesion;
public static String usuarioSesion;
public static String nombreSesion;
public static String numeroPedido;
public static String listcode;


/////////////////////
public static String plant;
public static String almacen;
public static String contado;
public static String credito;
public static String length;
public static String latitude;


public static String getImei() {
    return imei;
}

public static void setImei(String imei) {
    Usuario.imei = imei;
}

public static String getNumeroPedido() {
    return numeroPedido;
}

public static void setNumeroPedido(String numeroPedido) {
    Usuario.numeroPedido = numeroPedido;
}

public static String getCompaniaSesion() {
    return companiaSesion;
}

public static void setCompaniaSesion(String companiaSesion) {
    Usuario.companiaSesion = companiaSesion;
}

public static String getUsuarioSesion() {
    return usuarioSesion;
}

public static void setUsuarioSesion(String usuarioSesion) {
    Usuario.usuarioSesion = usuarioSesion;
}

public static String getListcode() {
    return listcode;
}

public static void setListcode(String listcode) {
    Usuario.listcode = listcode;
}

public static String getNombreSesion() {
    return nombreSesion;
}

public static void setNombreSesion(String nombreSesion) {
    Usuario.nombreSesion = nombreSesion;
}

public static String getPlant() {
    return plant;
}

public static void setPlant(String plant) {
    Usuario.plant = plant;
}

public static String getAlmacen() {
    return almacen;
}

public static void setAlmacen(String almacen) {
    Usuario.almacen = almacen;
}

public static String getContado() {
    return contado;
}

public static void setContado(String contado) {
    Usuario.contado = contado;
}

public static String getCredito() {
    return credito;
}

public static void setCredito(String credito) {
    Usuario.credito = credito;
}

public static String getLength() {
    return length;
}

public static void setLength(String length) {
    Usuario.length = length;
}

public static String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public static void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    Usuario.latitude = latitude;
}
}
```

Comment: Con solo la clase es difícil determinar que sucede, por favor comparte el código donde usas la clase, donde invocas el webService y como instancias a el objeto de la clase

Comment: Por lo que se ve son setter/getter, normales, sin problemas. No vuelves crear una instancia la clase por error? Has probado haciendo static la Class? Una Clase Singleton.

Comment: @FedericoMadoery no he probado haciendo static la clase, voy a ver que tal me va.

Comment: @IvanFontalvo la web service ejecuta muy bien todo. la instancia del objeto es una sola linea : Usuario.getUsuarioSesion() o Usuario.setUsuarioSesion("cualquier cosa") como las variables son static se pueden llamar directamente desde la clase pública sin instancias.

Comment: es una sola invacion al webService ? o son varias ? puede que como tienes los campos statics y no estas instanciando una nueva clase , el webService te retorne vacio o algo si y por ende los valores cambien

Comment: @IvanFontalvo solo uso una vez la webservice. esos valores que me retorna la webservice los almaceno en la clase de arriba. Luego, llamo a esas variables y las uso, pero de pronto se limpian. nunca me retorna vacío.

Comment: Se necesita absolutamente ver el código en el cual dices que se te limpian las variables.